# How do I get the number of hours I have used my EC2 instance for? AWS EC2 billing

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance which is billed by the hour, I am trying to see for `how many hours I have used EC2 in the current month`. Is there a dashboard in AWS console which displays similar data?

Comment: posted solution, did it work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should work for you.

- Go to billing dashboard.
- Under **billing** -> `bills.`
- Select `the month` **by default its current.**
- **under ec2, click the region.**
- **You will see what kind of instance and for how many hourse with its cost**

for example
[image]

Comment: Is there anyway to refine this by tags ?

Comment: yes using cost allocation tags, It would be great if you cn open a new question https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/activate-built-in-tags.html