# AWS Billing for a service that I did not use

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-billing

AWS Charged me a lot for `Lightsail` which I don't even remember using. not even once.
Or am I wrong? does it come with one of the services that I have been using?

These are the following services that I've been using:

```
1. EC2 - Which I terminated last April
2. S3 Bucket
3. Route53
4. Free tier RDS
```

Can someone explain to me why AWS charged me for `lightsail` usage?

**EDITED**
What's more problematic is that, I have setup only 1 EC2 instance for a certain region and the AWS Billed me for another 2 instances of EC2 from different regions. WTH

Comment: Sometime ago, I decide to give a try for AWS Workspaces, but just one day. After some months on my bill was charged me the use of AWS Workspaces, and I was surprised because I didn't use it. But... I forgot to delete my workspaces. I emailed them for a refund and they did it. Is it something similar? Have you checked in all your regions? You can find in your bill details which regions were used.

Comment: Please Edit your question to show the entries from the "Bill Details" of your billing dashboard. It should show a Service name, a Region and a Description of the charges. You can **look in AWS CloudTrail** to see the requests that AWS received to create resources -- they will have timestamps and the IP address of the requester. If what you say is true, then perhaps your account has been compromised?

Comment: create AWS support ticket and they will answer you questions, in most cases if you are unintentional use of them will be refuned. I had a good expeirience with them most of the time they listen and explain correctly, and refund once off.

Comment: Before reaching out to aws support just check your aws bills , this answer tells how https://stackoverflow.com/a/67337513/13126651 exactly and if you think you actually didnt use it just raise a ticket :)

Answer (score 0):

AWS calculates service charge for all the regions individually. So we need to be very careful when creating any resources. Just explore the AWS bill, it will give the detail which resource is being charged in what particular region.

Here are a few reasons why you might have incurred unexpected charges with your Amazon Lightsail plan:

- You signed up for the Lightsail plan that comes with the one-month free trial, but the free trial expired.
- You signed up for a more expensive Lightsail plan than you meant to.
- You signed up for Lightsail without meaning to.
- You exceeded your monthly data transfer allowance.

Answer (score 0):

Please check detailed bill from the dashboard, from your question there might be few possibilities:

- You may given your credentials to your friend who might have
  tried/used your account to do R&D and forgot to mention it you.
- If anyone have created a single resource and which is still running -
  exceeding the free tier limit you may be charged for it.

Resolution:

- Please connect with AWS Support team, you can reach out to them by
  using support center, they will help you resolve the problem in the
  best way possible.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer that might differ from the other answers here.
In AWS you have "out of the box" tags that you can use. It is automatically generated.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/awsaccountbilling/latest/aboutv2/aws-tags.html

> The AWS generated tags createdBy is a tag that AWS defines and applies
> to supported AWS resources for cost allocation purposes.

If you enable it, you can filter it in the Billing service (Cost explorer) to see who created the services

Answer (score -1):

This is a difficult question to answer from an outsider's perspective - but if you'd like you can try and sign up for a service named [Vantage](https://vantage.sh). They'll at least be able to plug into AWS billing APIs and give you the specific date for which these costs were incurred which may help narrow it down.

If you have less than $500 in AWS costs, I believe its free. Might be worth a shot. You can also attempt to open a support ticket with AWS or try to get in contact with Vantage support.